# Animate Google Chart from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-visualization

All of the examples on how to animate don't cover if the chart is created by JSON data.  They all use static data.  (See [Transition Animation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation).)

This is my code that gets my data via JSON.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        $.post('/Weight/WeightAreaChartData', {}, function (data) {
            var tdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
            var options = {
                title: 'Weight Lost & Gained This Month',
                hAxis: { title: 'Day of Month', titleTextStyle: { color: '#1E4A08'} },
                vAxis: { title: 'Lbs.', titleTextStyle: { color: '#1E4A08' } },
                chartArea: { left: 50, top: 30, width: "75%" },
                colors: ['#FF8100'],
                animation:{
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'in'
                },
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(
                document.getElementById('chart_div')
            );

            chart.draw(tdata, options);
        });
    }
</script>
```

I have a button that redraws the chart successfully. However, it doesn't animate. How can I make the chart animate? Thank you for your help.

```
 $('#myBtn').click(function () {
      drawChart();
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As eluded to by [@FelipeFonseca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1914514/felipe-fonseca), you're overwriting the chart each time `#myBtn is clicked`. Try doing this instead:

```
(function (global, undef) {
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    var options = {
        title: 'Weight Lost & Gained This Month',
        hAxis: { title: 'Day of Month', titleTextStyle: { color: '#1E4A08'} },
        vAxis: { title: 'Lbs.', titleTextStyle: { color: '#1E4A08' } },
        chartArea: { left: 50, top: 30, width: "75%" },
        colors: ['#FF8100'],
        animation:{
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'in'
        }
    };

    var chart;
    function drawChart() {
        $.post('/Weight/WeightAreaChartData', {}, function (data) {
            var tdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

            if (!chart) {
                chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(
                    document.getElementById('chart_div')
                );
            }

            chart.draw(tdata, options);
        });
    }

})(this);
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but I assume you have.  I have marked it as the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe cause you're creating the chart everytime?

Try to make `chart` a global variable and try again